# XML Assign More Than One Result To PHP Variable

Tags: php, xml, variables

I have done a bit of searching on this, but am just not sure I am searching for the right thing. Examples and things I have found have just confused me and possibly sent me in the wrong direction.

I am trying to figure out a php while statement, or if statement to return the results of XML output. The thing is the row/section I need may not always be the same number of results returned. For example there are ShoutCast streams, some have 1 mount point, and some have 3 mount points. Each mount point can have a different amount of listeners tuned in to that particular mount.

My Goal: To get the integer from all mount points returned in the XML, add them together to make a grand total of listeners.

The XML

```
<centovacast version="3.1.2" host="host.net">
<response type="success">
<message>Complete</message>
<data>
<status>
<mount>/stream</mount>
<sid>1</sid>
<listenercount>31</listenercount>
<genre>Blues</genre>
<url>http://www.websiteurl.com</url>
<title>Streams Name</title>
<currentsong>Artist Name - Track Name</currentsong>
<bitrate>128</bitrate>
<sourceconnected>1</sourceconnected>
<codec>audio/mpeg</codec>
<displayname>/stream</displayname>
<serverstate>1</serverstate>
<appstate>
<sctrans2>1</sctrans2>
</appstate>
<sourcestate>1</sourcestate>
<reseller/>
<useserver>1</useserver>
<ipaddress>11.11.111.111</ipaddress>
<port>8031</port>
<proxy>0</proxy>
<servertype>ShoutCast2</servertype>
<sourcetype>sctrans2</sourcetype>
</status>
<mountpoints>
<row>
<mount>/stream</mount>
<sid>1</sid>
<listenercount>31</listenercount>
<genre>Blues</genre>
<url>http://www.websiteurl.com</url>
<title>Stream Title Name</title>
<currentsong>Artist Name - Track Name</currentsong>
<bitrate>128</bitrate>
<sourceconnected>1</sourceconnected>
<codec>audio/mpeg</codec>
<displayname>/stream</displayname>
</row>
<row>
<mount>/live</mount>
<sid>2</sid>
<listenercount>0</listenercount>
<genre/>
<url/>
<title/>
<currentsong/>
<bitrate>0</bitrate>
<sourceconnected>0</sourceconnected>
<codec/>
<displayname>/live</displayname>
</row>
</mountpoints>
</data>
</response>
</centovacast>
```

So on the above I know how to pull the listeners for each mount individually using the following code.

```
$countlisteners->response->data->mountpoints->row[0]->listenercount;
```

That gives me the result for the first mount, and switching the 0 to a 1 gives me the second mount, so on and so forth.

What I need is for php that will count how many of those mounts exist, and assign each result to a variable I can then use to add together to get a grand total. Is there a way to do this?

What about doing something like this?

```
$countlisteners = simplexml_load_file('http://urltoxml.com');
foreach($countlisteners->response->data->mountpoints->row->listenercount as $result){
$total = $result;
echo $total;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. So simplistic, yet hard to figure out.

```
$total = 0;
foreach($countlisteners->response->data->mountpoints->row as $result){

$total += $result->listenercount;
$items++;

}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOMDocument for extracting all ***mountpoint*** tags

```
<?php
$xml="Your xml document content here";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('mountpoints');
foreach ($mountpoints as $mountpoints) {
echo $mountpoints->nodeValue;
     //you can add your count variable here
     //nodeValues can be assigned to varables
 }
?>
```

Comment: so the only thing I need to change in the above code would be the XML document location? Then how do I use nodeValue to loop for each result returned? Also is nodeValue something I would need to change to listenercount...or do I leave it as nodeValue...sorry I am a novice with XML and PHP. I appreciate the assistance in helping me learn a bit.

Comment: i edited my original post to include something I tried as I couldn't get your example to work with the DOM.

Comment: please see the offical documentation  http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 0):

You normally do that with Xpath. It's a query language for XML documents.

You're interested in all `listenercount` elements, the Xpath expression for these elements could be as simple as:

```
//listenercount
```

When you now use SimpleXML to parse the document, the following line of code gives you three **SimpleXMLElement**s inside an array that represent the three values you want to create the sum of:

```
$array = simplexml_load_string($buffer)->xpath('//listenercount');
```

As you need the sum of the integer values of these three elements, it can be easily processed with `array_map` and `array_sum`:

```
$sum   = array_sum(array_map('intval', $array));
```

And this gives you in `$sum` what you're looking for:

```
var_dump($sum); # int(62)
```

I hope this sheds you some light why it's often better to get the information you're looking for with an xpath query from the document instead of writing many lines of code to traverse the document "on your own".

The full example:

```
$buffer = <<<XML
<centovacast version="3.1.2" host="host.net">
<response type="success">
<message>Complete</message>
<data>
<status>
<mount>/stream</mount>
<sid>1</sid>
<listenercount>31</listenercount>
<genre>Blues</genre>
<url>http://www.websiteurl.com</url>
<title>Streams Name</title>
<currentsong>Artist Name - Track Name</currentsong>
<bitrate>128</bitrate>
<sourceconnected>1</sourceconnected>
<codec>audio/mpeg</codec>
<displayname>/stream</displayname>
<serverstate>1</serverstate>
<appstate>
<sctrans2>1</sctrans2>
</appstate>
<sourcestate>1</sourcestate>
<reseller/>
<useserver>1</useserver>
<ipaddress>11.11.111.111</ipaddress>
<port>8031</port>
<proxy>0</proxy>
<servertype>ShoutCast2</servertype>
<sourcetype>sctrans2</sourcetype>
</status>
<mountpoints>
<row>
<mount>/stream</mount>
<sid>1</sid>
<listenercount>31</listenercount>
<genre>Blues</genre>
<url>http://www.websiteurl.com</url>
<title>Stream Title Name</title>
<currentsong>Artist Name - Track Name</currentsong>
<bitrate>128</bitrate>
<sourceconnected>1</sourceconnected>
<codec>audio/mpeg</codec>
<displayname>/stream</displayname>
</row>
<row>
<mount>/live</mount>
<sid>2</sid>
<listenercount>0</listenercount>
<genre/>
<url/>
<title/>
<currentsong/>
<bitrate>0</bitrate>
<sourceconnected>0</sourceconnected>
<codec/>
<displayname>/live</displayname>
</row>
</mountpoints>
</data>
</response>
</centovacast>
XML;

$array = simplexml_load_string($buffer)->xpath('//listenercount');
$sum   = array_sum(array_map('intval', $array));
var_dump($sum);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this way as well.